# Are there any resources for learn making BSD-like systems like NetBSD and OpenBSD?

Tags: bsd

Don't tell me learn LFS (Linux from scratch) and make your Linux distribution. I interested on BSD-like systems. I want to become like Theo de Raadt (founder and leader of the OpenBSD and NetBSD) and make some BSD-like systems.
 I want to know how they take the kernel and other components of the operating systems and everything that is related to the creation of BSD systems and will make the BSD-like operating systems. Are there any resources books or anything else to learn and make BSD-like systems like NetBSD and OpenBSD?

Comment: Don't tell me learn piano from scratch. I'm interested in brass music. I want to become like Louis Armstrong and make some trumpet world hits. I want to know how they use their lips and other parts of the body and everything that is related to the creation of brass sounds. Are there any resources books or anything else to learn and make brass music like jazz or classics?

Comment: Why are you kidding me? I said that LFS does not belong to unix because LFS is linux but I want to learn how to make a BSD-like system. If you do not know the difference and can not distinguish Unix from Linux, then you do not belong here @Philippos.

Comment: What makes you think I'm interested in any UNIX vs. Linux discussion? My comment obviously tries to mirror your request to make you understand why it needs to be closed. You are not to judge who belongs here.

Comment: almost every OS share basics mecanism specially ones respecting POSIX. If you want to join BSD go for it join the mailling list try correcting bug, ask learn. But you have to understand that BSD is nothing like it was before, it more complex and featurefull which it might not have been at the beginning. It's way harder to understand how a kernel work today as compared to kernel from late 80's.  you could start to read minix code. It would show you a lot.

Comment: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/

Comment: @Kiwy Minix's kernel is Microkernel but FreeBSD's kernel is Monolithic  What can I learn in minix code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm willing to bet all the money I don't have, that the knowledge you're looking for is not in a book or website, but rather in the minds of the developers of those projects. Think about it: *Why in the world would they take the time to document such in-depth knowledge? For what purpose?*

You're best bet is to:

1. Join the developer mailing lists and participate.
2. Participate in the hackathons and other similar events where developers work on releases.

Comment: I liked the creation and promotion of bsd-like systems and I want to learn how to create bsd-like systems. I know python and I know UNIX in the middle level. I still can not participate in the development of operating systems. Now I want to learn what to learn to create bsd-like systems and study it and then join and create an operating system. What do I need to learn?

Comment: Like you, I was interested in creating my own operating system. Unlike the "old days" there are now operating systems designed for the purpose of study. Minix is one, but you may find Genode interesting. There are essentially "OS kits" you can use to get started. There's an OS written in Rust which might help since you're coming from a high-level programming language. But regarding BSD, your best bet is to participate in whatever capacity you can; You'll learn more that way than any other. A book that might help is "Operating System Concepts" (it's got dinosaurs on the cover).

Comment: Untold thousands have woken up with the goal "I'll make a new operating system from scratch", a few hundred got it working (mostly by taking an existing one and hacking on it), a handful is of any relevance.